# Second Monitor's Resolution not correct

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution

Ubuntu 16.04
Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition with Ubuntu pre loaded from dell.

Searching around I figured out how to add a resolution to my OS, it shows up in the setting>displays GUI. I've selected the new resolution, 1440 x 900 60, for the second monitor. The choice remains selected after re boot, etc. Problem is the monitor is not displaying at the selected resolution, instead it's much lower.

I use this same monitor on a Macbook Air and I verified it's at 1440 x 900 60 which is it's default setting.

Any Ideas?

Thanks!